# Converting existing Angular App with completly New UI design

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular6

I have one Angular project, which is already created by another developer.

Now the requirement is to create a complete New UI with already existing features.

I have two options:

1. Create a new Angular app and add one by one features with new UI changes
2. Add new UI changed in existing projects with one by one features.

I am confused, which one I should pick up.
The existing code is very complex and messy.

I also want to change the design architecture with modular design, because it doesn't follow lazy loading and  each & every module is loading in starting only.

Please help me to finalize the design.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is always wiser to do incremental changes. It leads to better control, focus and it is highly efficient. Change portions of the application as you keep moving forward until the old UI is history and not even there :-)

Comment: Also, remember if there is a customer base for this application you got to keep the application stable and too much change will create chaos.